# Retrieving links using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, screen-scraping, hyperlink

I posted this up a day or two ago, received an answer which worked on JSfiddle, but didn't work on my actual code.

```
  <div id="PublicResults">
<h2>
<dl>
<dt>
<a onmouseout="swho.alone.OnMouseOut(event)" onmouseover="swho.alone.showPopup(event, 'DR647E481', 'pra**', '', '', 'everyone', 'closed')" href="/SWApp/detailAction.do?key=DR647E481&search=pra**&soundex=&stanfordonly=&affilfilter=everyone&filters=closed">Ajay Prakash</a>
</dt>
```

Now, I tried $jq("#PublicResults a").attr("href"), which worked in jsfiddle, but isn't working on the page (my console reads undefined). However, when I try $jq("#PublicResults a[href]").attr("href"), I get the url of the current webpage- so I guess the issue is that .attr() is returning only the first element

So my question is twofold- if what I wrote just above is correct, how do I make .attr() return all elements. If not, what should I do to retrieve the url in href?

Answer (score 2):

You have to **loop** troughout the array list of all links do you want to scraping:

```
$jq("#PublicResults a").each(function()
{
   alert($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your jQuery instance tied to `$jq()` (instead of the usual `$()` or `jQuery()`), then `$jq("#PublicResults a[href]").attr("href")` should work. Could you post a link to where it doesn't work?

I suspect one of the following:

1. You may be running the jQuery code before the `#PublicResults` element is added to the page
2. It is possible that the `$jq()` function is not available
3. Something else may be altering your link href

Comment: er the $jq function works when I do "$jq("#PublicResults a[href]"), and I 'm running the code on a console in firebug to test it

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to extract all of the href's from the jQuery wrapped objects. eg.

```
$('...').map(function() { return $(this).attr('href'); });
```

This returns a jQuery wrapped array, to get a normal JavaScript one, just use `.get()`.

Comment: also, how do I load the url from which I'm scraping with this?